# CLRS like book for blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

I am writing a blockchain as a side project in Go and I am struggling to find good a theoretical treatise on the subject.

The information online is either too basic or too specific.

Thanks

Comment: Reading recommendations are typically not a good fit for this site, as they are very subjective and a matter of opinion; see our [help/dont-ask].  What counts as "good" is a matter of opinion.  You can make the question suitable by identifying specific requirements, and listing what resources you've found which requirement(s) each one fails to meet.